# Webscraping with Xpath in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

From what I've seen the method to derive a path for Xpath to scrape a page  is not totally clear to me. I'm trying to use Xpath in python to scrape the wikipedia article for states and capitals to get a list of states and a list of capitals, but so far I've had no luck when trying to figure out the correct path to use. I've tried inspecting the element and copying the Xpath there but I still have had no luck. I'm looking for someone to explain a method to figure out the correct xpath to use to grab certain elements in a page.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_capitals_in_the_United_States')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#creating list of states
state = tree.xpath('xpath')
#list of capitals
capital = tree.xpath('xpath')

print 'State: ', state
print 'Capital: ', capital
```

Two of the xpaths I've tried so far have been:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a

//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

Comment: Can you show us what xpath expression you've tried so far?  There's really no magic in terms of figuring one out; you just need to look at the HTML code carefully and construct a path that matches the structure of the document.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it to show some of the paths I've tried before, those are gotten using "copy xpath" in the inspect element browser of chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an expression that will get you the table.  Here's one that works:

```
>>> tree.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]')
[<Element table at 0x7f9dd7322578>]
```

You want the first table in that `div` (hence the `[1]`) and there does not appear to be a `tbody` element there.

You could iterate over the rows in that table like this:

```
for row in tree.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr')[1:]:
```

Within that loop, the state name is:

```
row[0][0].text
```

That is the first child of the row (which is a `<td>` element), and then first child of that (which is an `<a>` element), and then the text content of that element.

And the capital is:

```
row[3][0].text
```

So:

```
>>> for row in tree.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr')[1:]:
...   st = row[0][0].text
...   cap = row[3][0].text
...   print 'The capital of %s is %s' % (st, cap)
The capital of Alabama is Montgomery
The capital of Alaska is Juneau
The capital of Arizona is Phoenix
[...]
```

You can get all the state names like this:

```
>>> tree.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/a/text()')
['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
```

Comment: Okay wow thanks! That answers my question. However, I do have a couple of questions about the solution. First, at the end of the loop statement, what does `[1:]:` mean? Second, I get that in order to traverse a table you'd have one variable for row and one for column, but why when we're assigning state and capital do we have that second variable set to 0 and not some sort of iterator? I'm fairly new to Python coming from a C++ background so forgive me if the answer is obvious. Thanks again!

Comment: If you have a list in some variable `var`, then `var[1:]` means "everything but the first element". In this case, the first row of the table is the headers, so we discard that. I'm not sure what you mean by "...second variable set to 0"; I'm not setting any variables to 0.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean by setting it to 0 is in the line `st = row[0][0].text` I understand why the first one is 0 because that's where the state column is, but why is the second one 0? If that's where the particular state is wouldn't that be the value iterated as you were going through `tree.xpath`.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I got it. What it is is what you were saying here:

"That is the first child of the row (which is a <td> element), and then first child of that (which is an <a> element), and then the text content of that element."

so they have to deal with how elements are gotten from the html?

Comment: Right. `row[0]` is `<td><a>...</a></td>`. `row[0][0]` is `<a>...</a>`.  And sure, you have to deal with the structure of the document...like I said earlier, no magic! You could use additional xpath expressions (`row.xpath('td[1]/a/text()')`) here instead of indexes like this and get the same result.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @larsks ! You were very helpful!